# Counting item number in Python 'for'?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for x in y, type iteration in python. Can I find out what iteration I'm currently on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894323/for-x-in-y-type-iteration-in-python-can-i-find-out-what-iteration-im-currentl)
>   [Iteration count in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590810/iteration-count-in-python)

Kind of hard to explain, but when I run something like this:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'kiwi']

for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit.capitalize()
```

It gives me this, as expected:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Strawberry
Kiwi
```

How would I edit that code so that it would "count" the amount of times it's performing the `for`, and print this?

```
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Banana
4 Strawberry
5 Kiwi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [for x in y, type iteration in python. Can I find out what iteration I'm currently on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894323/for-x-in-y-type-iteration-in-python-can-i-find-out-what-iteration-im-currentl) and [Iteration count in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590810/iteration-count-in-python) and [Identify which iteration you are on in a loop in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751092/identify-which-iteration-you-are-on-in-a-loop-in-python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i,fruit in enumerate(fruits, 1):
    print i, fruit.capitalize()
```

will do what you want and print:

```
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Banana
4 Strawberry
5 Kiwi
```

By default [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) will start generating an index with 0 if not specified, but you can specify the starting value as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring `enumerate(iterable)`, you could just count yourself:

```
i = 0
for fruit in fruits:
    i += 1
    print i, fruit.capitalize()
```

Comment: Why do it manually in an uglier way? -1. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting this was a good way, but I wanted to point out to the OP how you could simply modify the existing code to accomplish what he wants - that it isn't a huge leap from what he had to what he wants, and to show what enumerate is essentially doing for you. But I guess we downvote less-than-optimal answers these days